# asp.net Chart Force Labels On X-Axis Staggered Evenly

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, charts

I'm creating a C# WinForms app that displays nearly real-time, time-based (~5s refresh rate) data from a SQL server using the WinForms Line Chart control. The fetching and inserting of data on the chart works just fine, it is just the formatting I'm having issues with.  The X-Axis contains the DateTime of each point and is set to display the date on the X-Axis.

The problem I'm encountering is the X-Axis labels not being displayed evenly across the chart.  I'm able to get the number of axis labels that I want, but they are not consistently in the same position on the axis.

Ideally I'd like to be able to set the number of x-axis labels, have a label at each ends of the chart, then the remaining labels evenly split across the rest of the chart.  Then every time new data is added to the chart the labels stay in the exact same spot, just the label text is updated.

Here are two pictures that should make it clear what I'm after.

The first picture is data from the range 16:10:00 to 16:11:00.

This is what I would like for any start/end date:

[image]

The second picture shows what happens when I add 5 seconds of new data and remove 5 seconds of old data.

Chart after refreshing with new data:

[image]

Here is the snippet of code that I use for my x-axis formatting.

```
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Seconds;              
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = timeDiff.TotalSeconds / numXTicks;
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = timeMin.ToOADate();
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = timeMax.ToOADate();
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "yyyy-MM-dd" + Environment.NewLine + "HH:mm:ss";
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.IsEndLabelVisible = true;
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsMarginVisible = true;
```

Thanks for any help.  Long time lurker and first time poster.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that may be curious I found a reasonable workaround by setting the IntervalType to MilliSeconds.

```
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Milliseconds;
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = unixDiff.TotalMilliseconds / numXTicks;
```

While this doesn't necessarily fix the x-axis labels in place, by having an Interval will multiply evenly across the chart and not result in a fraction of an interval the labels will be neatly labeled across the entire chart.